# sending picture to flash client. what technologies to use?

Tags: java, flash, client-server, blazeds, red5

The question is about the following operation:

1. Flash client sends TeX code (or file) to server.
2. TeX is compiled into picture.
3. Picture is sent back to client

As far as I can see the best way to do that is to use flash+java remoting. But, there're several java servers (looks like BlazeDS and Red5 are the most popular). Which one do you advise to use for my purposes? Note that steps 1-3 are not final, picture will be changed after that (e.g. some marks will be made).

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BlazeDS is intended for data streaming, Red5 for media streaming. According to your above mentioned requirements, the data streaming is fully suitable to your requirements. So you can choose BlazeDS.

Comment: Thank you. Now I realize what I should have asked, according to your terminology a question should be something like "Picture is data or media?".

Comment: @Eugeny89 It is data. Video and sound is media.